# Function to open and read a file in Python comes up with an error: NameError: name 'xxxx' is not defined

Tags: python, function, file

G'day all! I have this project to check if the user input data is in the file. It's all working on a Jupyter notebook but when I created a function `def`, I keep getting an error: NameError: name `'fread'` is not defined.

Here is the folder structure:

```
main_code
  initial_list
  user_input
  validate_user_input
```

The issue I believe is coming from the `validate_user_input` code:

```
def check_input():
    for line in fread:
        if ui in line.split():
            return line
```

Here is the `initial_list` code:

```
def initial_list():
    with open('test', mode='r+') as fopen:
        fread=fopen.readlines()
        return fread
```

Here is the `user_input` code:

```
def user_input():
    ui=input('Enter name here: ')
    return ui
```

And here is the `main_code` code:

```
from initial_list import initial_list
from user_input import user_input
from validate_user_input import validate_user_input

initial_list.initial_list()
user_input.user_input()
validate_user_input.check_input()
```

Note:

- all folders contain a **init**.py to call the function
- running the `main_code.py` enables me to input data (user_input)
- tried searching this online but no luck...crying...

Please help, Thank you in advance!

Comment: add the variable `fread` as parameter of your function `check_input()`

Comment: You have not defined `fread` variable in your `check_input`-function

Comment: I have added the "fread" 

`def check_input(myfread):`


but now im getting this error - `TypeError: check_input() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myfread'`

Comment: I also added `myfread  = initial_list()` to my initial list

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable fread as input to your function:

```
def check_input(fread):
  for line in fread:
      if ui in line.split():
          return line
```

And then when you run the function initial_list(), it should have an output that  is the fread input for the other one, like this.

```
myfread  = initial_list()
check_input(myfread)
```

Comment: still not getting it